# Using AWS API Gateway to POST email via AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-ses

I'm setting up an API from an App which allows the App user to contact someone for follow-up, but hides the email address from the sender (and allows it to be changed without a new release of the App).

I've managed to setup an AWS API Gateway GET method which sends email directly via SES

```
https://...aws.com/em/send/en?body=The+email+is+here
```

Using a path override of

```
Action=SendEmail
&Source=source%40mydomain.org
&Destination.ToAddresses.member.1=follow.up%40anydomain.com
&Message.Subject.Data=Request+For+Followup
&Message.Body.Text.Data={body}
```

I would much prefer to use a **`POST`** method - but am really struggling to work out what should go in the `Action` parameter and how to create the mapping template - or even if it is possible to create an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request without having to resort to a lambda function - although the AWS documentation does include a `$util.urlEncode()` function.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html

**Edit:**

I am trying to use a POST method to AWS Gateway and a POST to SES with the contents in the request body, but it is just not clear to me how to create the mapping template and I can't find any examples for SES.

Testing it with the mapping template (as per the example in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/query-interface-examples.html))

```
Source=source%40mydomain.org
&Destination.ToAddresses.member.1=follow.up%40anydomain.com
&Message.Subject.Data=Request+For+Followup
&Message.Body.Text.Data=The+message+goes+here
```

And a content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` AWS gateway gives the error:

```
{
"message": "Unsupported Media Type"
}
```

If I use a mapping template

```
{
"Action":"SendEmail",
"Source":"source@mydomain.org",
"Destination":{
    "ToAddresses":{
        "member":["follow.up@anydomain.com"]
        }
    },
"Message":{
    "Subject": {
        "Data":"Request For Followup"
        },
    "Body":{
        "Text":{
            "Data":"The message goes here"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and a content type of `application/json` AWS gateway gives the error

```
{
  "Output": {
    "__type": "com.amazon.coral.service#UnknownOperationException",
    "message": null
  },
  "Version": "1.0"
}
```

Comment: It's not clear from the question what you're specifically trying to achieve. Do you want to make API Gateway accept a POST method with the email contents in the request body? If so, it should be a simple change from what you have now. If you're having issues, please post the specific problem you're seeing. Note: If the SES API accepts data in the request body you will need to use a mapping template. If not you will need to use path override parameters as you have done.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I am trying to put the email contents in the request body, yes, but cannot work out what goes in the mapping template.

Comment: You need to model your integration according to the SES API. The mapping template output should match what SES expects in the request body for the SendEmail operation. It's not immediately obvious from the docs, but I don't expect they take the action/etc in the request body. I think you will need to send the data in the request path as you have done earlier.

Comment: Well; it seems sending it in the request path does work. But the documentation definitely appears to show request body is possible. Just a shame API Gateway does not support application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from outputting "x-www-form-urlencoded" from your mapping template if that's what SES expects. Your API can accept JSON and convert it to form data via "application/json" mapping template. You may need to override the integration content-type header to set it to "x-www-form-urlencoded" to send to SES though.

Comment: Sorry can't provide more details - may want to post in SES forums to get more details on their API spec in order to model it in APIG. Alternatively, you can use the AWS SDK and turn on verbose wire logging in order to inspect the HTTP requests made to SES.

Answer (score 1):

Your mapping template configuration must be in a POST format, not in the JSON, since [SES service doesn't support json](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/query-interface-examples.html).
For example, this config has worked out for me:

```
Action=SendEmail&
Message.Body.Text.Data=Some+text&
Message.Subject.Data=New+message&
ReturnPath=some@mail.io
&Destination.ToAddresses.member.1=some@destination.com
&Source=your@sender.email
```

Also, your path override must be `SendEmail` only for the case above